# D3 xlink: "href" appends image fine on Google Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, svg

I am trying to append an image tag on my landing page. I am getting it to work on *Google Chrome*, but not *Firefox*. To clarify, the images are showing up on the former and are not on the later. Has anyone else had this problem?

***Here is my HTML...***

```
<div id="viz"></div>
```

***Here is my D3 code...***

```
var SVG = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 870)
    .attr("height", 800)

d3.select('SVG')
    .append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href','../../static/disney/avengers.png')
    .attr('class', 'avengers')
    .attr('height', '75')
    .attr('width', '150')
    .attr('x', '350')
    .attr('y', '350')
```

I have scowered Stack Overflow and have yet to find any useful solutions to this quagmire. Also, I am using *Django*. Not sure if that has any effect on things. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess: try to put "px" after both height and width, like this: `.attr('height', 75 + 'px')`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado units are optional in SVG.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, I know that by now. That comment is from 10 months ago, when I was struggling with `dominant-baseline` in Firefox that, for some unknown reason, just worked when I added "px". Why was this question revived after so long?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado someone decided to provide an answer to it. That bumps it and everybody notices it again.

Answer (score 2):

SVG uses XML syntax which defines element names to be case-sensitive. Hence, doing a `d3.select('SVG')` should yield an empty seletion— which Firefox correctly does—because there is no uppercase `SVG` element. The following snippet will log `1` for both selections in Chrome, which is not correct, and log `1` and `0` in Firefox, which is the correct behaviour. As it turns out, IE 11 does also show the correct behavior.

```js
console.log(d3.select("svg").size());  // 1 in all browsers
console.log(d3.select("SVG").size());  // 0 in FF & IE 11; 1 in Chrome
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

With that in mind, the solution to your problem becomes easy. Change your selection to the correct `d3.select("svg")`.

Answer (score 0):

Or set `.attr('height', "100%").attr('width', "100%")`
I had the same problem. It appears I was missing "width" attribute.

Comment: The OP sets both height and width in the question.

Comment: You right. Just spent so much time for debugging my bug and thought it would be to good to share my experience.